# Is it common to find the first part of The Fellowship of the Ring by far the most enjoyable of the entire three-part epic saga?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-fellowship-of-the-ring, the-two-towers

Let's be clear: I *do* love the entire series. It is without a doubt an epic masterpiece, and it would probably make little sense to write ~1,500 pages about just Hobbiton and The Shire, with them never getting out into the bigger world and "nothing happening". It's not what I'm suggesting as an "improvement" of the story.

What I mean is that, when I recently set out to re-read the entire thing after more than twenty years since my last (and first) time, I found myself *really* enjoying the descriptions in the beginning, and the relatively "slow" pace that events unfold. It probably helps that I also *read* slowly, and knew that I wanted to remain there for as long as possible before the crazy adventures begun.

Unlike in "The Hobbit", the author takes his time to linger on in the beginnings; we aren't immediately thrown into some epic action battle with orcs/goblins/whatever. He doesn't cut straight from the Hobbit house to the encounter with the giants, as in the first book. Even those creepy riders are, in some sense, treated almost light-heartedly. Yes, they are very dangerous and evil, and they do pose a serious threat, but things are kept at some kind of "reasonable" level, which I really enjoyed. They still were familiar with the environments, and it was almost like they were going on a shorter trip to a nearby town to visit family members or something. A little "hobbit adventure". I guess it also helped that we, the readers, didn't know about Merry and Pippin being in on the truth to some extent.

In the Hollywood movie, they not only fast-forward the beginnings, but seem to entirely skip 99% of it, even in the "extended cut" edition. I could have easily taken an entire three-four hours movie of them just getting to Rivendell, and was shocked by how the viewer doesn't get any sense of space and time whatsoever for their initial, more "down to Earth" struggles.

Perhaps this is because I'm such a "hobbit" myself, who has zero interest in traveling around in the world (at least *this* world, in *this* age), but I must admit to feeling sadness once they had reached too far away from their homes. Once they came to Rivendell, as enchanting as it may be, I feel as if this "beginning part" was unambiguously over, and now began the "epic adventure". Literally. That's where the Fellowship was officially formed and embarked on the great mission to destroy the Ring.

I very much enjoyed the lengthy discussion they had with the elves, talking about (almost) all the important things they could predict in advance. In fact, I wish that part would've gone on much longer as well; it would've made a great last 30-45 minutes of the first movie (out of many), or even that Gandalf had sat with Frodo (and Sam) for much longer even back in Bag End, explaining various crucial things in-depth before they even set out in the first place. Both the original book and the movies (albeit to wildly different extents) seemed to miss the opportunity to really make us feel at home in Hobbiton/The Shire, instead opting to rush into action much quicker than I would have preferred.

As excitedly as I read each word from that point on (after they left Rivendell), slowly making myself through the novel over a number of months, feeling almost as if I were there as a member of the Fellowship, I could not shake off this feeling that the further away they got, and the "crazier" things happened to them, the less I could identify with the hobbits. By the end of the third book, with all the big celebrations and the taking back of their home town(s), they had truly transformed into confident *hobbit warriors* from all their hardships and frightening battles and meetings with important and mighty people, and the very end just filled me with an indescribable sorrow. The epilogue texts just made it even worse, talking about how Pippin and Merry died far away from their home and whatnot.

Perhaps all this says far more about myself and how I never reached "maturity" in my own sad life, and again, I understand that it could probably not have happened any other way and still remained an epic adventure and a timeless classic, but a part of me genuinely wishes that large parts of the adventure never happened, or that it was all scaled back quite a bit, or at least that Tolkien would've allowed there to be much more "build-up" and suspense, with more "little signs" or "bad omens" rather than full-on direct dangers happening all the time. At least for longer than what is the case.

I'm not trying to rewrite a classic with my own silly non-ideas, but nevertheless, it can't be denied that once they really "got going", I felt what the hobbits probably felt in their guts: endless dreadful walking in miserable and hostile environments. No more funny Tom Bombadil, no familiar areas, no "going camping for the weekend" atmosphere, etc. I did enjoy the brief scene where Sam cooked that rabbit dinner next door to Mordor, but it was sort of an anticlimax as Frodo mostly got upset that he almost revealed their position, and then they soon got a proper meal anyway, rendering Sam's thoughtful cooking virtually meaningless. I would've liked for Frodo and Sam to regain a lot of strength from it instead, so that they could go on for much longer as they were starving at that point; it would've been an example of a more "down to Earth" thing happening even late into the story. It's as if things *had* to get crazier and "bigger" all the time, which is probably at the core of my question/concern.

There are also other books for which loved the first half, such as "Epepe (Metropole)", where everything is initially excitingly mysterious and unknown, but where I find the second part mostly quite dull, after the main character has established some kind of routine in this world, and it is no longer about him looking around and trying to figure out where he was, how he got there, and why everything is so strange.

Am I just crazy and weird, or is this a common feeling that others also have?

Comment: Unfortunately your question is extremely opinion based. And as a Q&A site that focuses in objective answers in doesn’t quite match our format. You will, however, possibly find more luck on Reddit in places such as the “tolkienfans” subreddit or “lotr” subreddit!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! @Edlothiad is correct, this site is more focused on objective right/wrong answers. For more details, have a look at oour [help] and then take our [tour]!  When you've got enough reputation, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe). Share and enjoy!

Comment: There are actually some objective measures that could be brought to bear on this question, though it should be made clear first whether an answer based on the books or the movies is wanted. For example, which of the three movies made the most money? Which received the highest critical praise, e.g., on Rotten Tomatoes? Which of the books is referred to most often on Google? All of these would be based on aggregates of popular opinion, but that's what the OP wants to know about.

Comment: Well, when I last read it (in 1990), I liked that part best, along with the ending including The Scouring of the Shire. Together, these two parts show how much the hobbits have grown through their adventures (two of them literally so),

Comment: I noted that myself, and while it may be better discussed on the literature exchange, I think that the first book was deliberately very whimsical (and very enjoyable for me as I love the idyllic shire) in order to provide a stark contrast to just how bad everything got. Maybe a metaphor for young men tromping off to WWI with dreams of glory and heroism, only to find hell?

Answer (score 2):

Fritz Leiber seemed to think so, and he asserted that the sentiment was commonplace (even if not everyone would admit to it):*

> There’s no arguing that a vast number of people—intelligent, educated, and sensitive people, I mean—young and old (but especially the former) — are tremendously and enduringly enthusiastic about Tolkien’s trilogy, yet I do meet quite a few whose reactions are much like my own.  We almost always start with, “The ents are great!  Oh boy, yes. **And that first part of the quest with the black riders in the distance and Strider a mystery—that’s great too. Oh and yes, the first appearance of the Nazgul** and the Balrog....”  At about which point the silence begins and we search our memories and look at each other rather guiltily—exciting things should spring to mind, but they don’t.

It appears from this that Book I (the first half of *The Fellowship of the Ring*) was the part that Leiber found the most compelling.

*I don't know the original source the Leiber quote, but it was quoted approvingly by Lin Carter in *Imaginary Worlds*.